# computed property "showHazteSocioPopup" was assigned to but it has no setter

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Can someone explain to me this error. the idea in this component is to show a pop-up once that it receive a boolean property from the father component. And it works but when I try to close the Pop-up I have the error. Thanks in advance.

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="showHazteSocioPopup" max-width="700">
    <v-sheet>
      <p id="test-v-dialog">
        Pop-Ups
      </p>
      <v-btn @click="showMemberPanel">
        Hacerse Socio
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="hideMemberPanel">
        Seguir con la compra
      </v-btn>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PopupCheckoutActeSocio',
  props: {
    isVisible: {
      type: Boolean,
      require: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    showHazteSocioPopup () {
      return this.isVisible
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showMemberPanel () {
      this.showHazteSocioPopup = false
      this.$store.commit('setPanelComponent', 'alta-socio-checkout')
      this.$store.commit('setPanelVisibility', true)
    },
    hideMemberPanel () {
      this.showHazteSocioPopup = false
      this.$parent.finishOrder()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change a `computed` property. You can use [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) as follows:

```
showHazteSocioPopup:{
     //getter
     get: function () {
          return this.isVisible
     },
     // setter
     set: function (newValue) {
          this.$emit('isVisibleChanged',newValue)
     }
}
```

So in the parent, add this listener and method:

```
@isVisibleChanged="isVisibleChanged"
```

```
isVisibleChanged(newVal){
     this.inVisible=newVal
}
```

A simpler solution would be directly emitting the new value to the parent instead of adding a setter:

```
 computed: {
    showHazteSocioPopup () {
      return this.isVisible
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showMemberPanel () {
      this.$emit('isVisibleChanged',false)
      this.$store.commit('setPanelComponent', 'alta-socio-checkout')
      this.$store.commit('setPanelVisibility', true)
    },
    hideMemberPanel () {
      this.$emit('isVisibleChanged',false);
      this.$parent.finishOrder()
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried using your idea, as you can see below
`code`
  computed: {
    showHazteSocioPopup:{
      get: function () {
          return this.isVisible
      },
      set: function (newValue) {
          this.isVisible = newValue
      }
    }
  },
`code`

and now I have another error
_italic_Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "isVisible"_italic_

Comment: Oh, since ``inVisible`` is a ``prop``, you cannot directly change it from the component. You can ``emit`` its value to the parent and change it there as the updated code states. Or you can keep your code and use the ``emit`` instead of directly changing the computed property

Comment: @MiguelFernándezLizarbe please mark the answer as the solution if it solved your problem, or let me know if you are facing other issues.

Comment: Btw, your code seems complicated. You don't need a computed property here. Why don't you use ``v-if="isVisible"`` instead of ``v-model="showHazteSocioPopup"``? And keep the emits as explained above